# Is it possible to completely override Django's auto admin theme?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-admin, themes

I want to use one of the many bootstrap responsive themes to override Django's auto admin style. I've only donde the tutorial but I'm not sure if messing with the CSS will break the tool. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django documents have a section on [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

There is someone also has port twitter bootstrap for Django admin. You should take a look at [django-admin-bootstrap](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped). Works on Django 1.7+.